# HttpWebRequest check for allowed domain

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a question regarding the allowing the user to connecto only allowed domain name.

So what i have in mind is: i have a list of domaina names, like *.domain1.com; *.domain2.com etc ...

Then somwhere in the code I have to check if the request or response is really from that kind of domain, if it is not, i should throw a message.

Here i have the code which i have at this moment:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return stream;
            }
        }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ResponseUri` property:

```
HashSet<String> allowedDomains = new HashSet<String>()
                                 {
                                         "domain1.com",
                                         "domain2.com"
                                 };

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    if (!allowedDomains.Contains(response.ResponseUri.Host))
    {
        throw new IllegalDomainException();
    }
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

You might want modify the comparisson: for example, iterate backwards over the result of `request.ResponseUri.Host.Split(".")` comparing each part in turn with the equivalent from the allowedDomains value, and you might want to think about where the check is done: do you want redirection to be permitted?  If so, create a Uri object from the user input, and check the `Host` property of that.

Comment: Thanks man it is really cool, but do you know maybe how could do a regex replace for example i got the the hsot it will be something like sub.domain.com and i need =>*.domain.com could you help me with regex.replace, saying replace the first letters before the dot by *?

Comment: `System.Linq`, has an extension method `HashSet.Contains` can take an `IEqualityComparer`.  Implement a class exposing that, with the required regex code in the `Equals` method.

Comment: Alternativly, change the `HashSet<String>` for a `HashSet<Regex>`, and use `allowedDomains.Any(re => re.Match(request.Host).Success)` instead of the `allowedDomains.Contains(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is acquired using the *UrlReferer* HTTP header, but this header isn't mandatory: it can be set or not. It depends on the HTTP server.

The whole header may be accessed using the [`HttpWebResponse.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers.aspx) property:

```
((HttpWebResponse)response).Headers["Referer"]
```

Honestly, I would like to suggest you that the best solution is to use an *application key* (an arbitrary identifier). For example a `Guid` (it may work for very simple cases).

In the Web server you can define default headers (if your Web sites are developed using ASP.NET, [you can do it in the *web.config*](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders)) so any request coming from the whole server will contain your arbitrary HTTP header with the *appkey*.

That is, you can define an arbitrary header that may identify the HTTP responses coming from your Web sites. For example: **MySite_AppKey**. Using this approach you should verify that any HTTP response contains the whole **MySite_AppKey** and check if the whole *appkey* is permitted in some *white list*.

Sample pseudo-code:

```
if(AppAuthorizationManager.IsAuthorized(response.Headers["MySite_AppKey]))
{
     // Do stuff for the authorized request
}
```

*Note that I'm describing a very simple implementation*.